# sbcl encoding error only when executed from prompt?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a code that if executed from the slime prompt inside emacs run with no error. If I started sbcl from the prompt, I got the error:

```
* (ei:proc-file "BRAvESP000.log" "lixo")

debugger invoked on a SB-INT:STREAM-ENCODING-ERROR:
  :UTF-8 stream encoding error on
  #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /Users/arademaker/work/IBM/scolapp/lixo"
    {10049E8FF3}>:

    the character with code 55357 cannot be encoded.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [OUTPUT-NOTHING    ] Skip output of this character.
  1: [OUTPUT-REPLACEMENT] Output replacement string.
  2: [ABORT             ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

(SB-IMPL::STREAM-ENCODING-ERROR-AND-HANDLE #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /Users/arademaker/work/IBM/scolapp/lixo" {10049E8FF3}> 55357)
0]
```

The mistery is that in both cases I am using the same sbcl 1.1.8 and the same machine, Mac OS 10.8.4. Any idea?

The code:

```
(defun proc-file (filein fileout &key (fn-convert #'identity))
  (with-open-file (fout fileout
                   :direction :output
                   :if-exists :supersede
                   :external-format :utf8)
    (with-open-file (fin filein :external-format :utf8)
      (loop for line = (read-line fin nil)
        while line
        do 
        (handler-case
        (let* ((line (ppcre:regex-replace "^.*{jsonTweet=" line "{\"jsonTweet\":"))
               (data (gethash "jsonTweet" (yason:parse line))))
          (yason:encode (funcall fn-convert (yason:parse data)) fout)
          (format fout "~%"))
          (end-of-file ()
        (format *standard-output* "Error[~a]: ~a~%" filein line)))))))
```

Comment: I suggest that you start by assuming this isn't a yason problem -- we'll find out quickly if it is -- and add the following to your code: `(format *standard-output* "~&~{~x~^ ~}" (map 'list 'char-code line))`. Is the final line in the failing case the same as the corresponding line in the SLIME environment?

Comment: Maybe there are files named BRAvESP000.log in more than one directory, and the current directory is different if you're in SLIME or if you're launching SBCL manually. Try absolute paths.

Comment: If the character code is not a mistake, it belongs to the Unicode range of surrogate pairs. These aren't characters of UTF-8 encoding, they are reserved for use with UTF-16. Here's my guess: there's a modern tradition in web design to use private plane characters together with a special font to serve as icons (such as various arrows, bullets and so on). Twitter, in particular, does that (so does Github for example too). This is a way for an HTML page to save on loading images (as these are vector outlines from a special font). I would imagine that Emacs deals with them before sending.

Comment: But SBCL on its own doesn't. I think you would be fine if you simply delete those, or replace with something less offensive.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a bug in yason.  JSON requires that if a non BMP character is escaped, it is done so through a surrogate pair.  Here's a simple example with U+10000 (which is optionally escaped in json as "\ud800\udc00"; I use babel as babel's conversion is less strin):

```
(map 'list #'char-code (yason:parse "\"\\ud800\\udc00\"")) 
  => (55296 56320)
```

unicode code point 55296 (decimal) is the start for a surrogate pair, and should not appear except as a surrogate pair in UTF-16.  Fortunately it can be easily worked around by using babel to encode the string to UTF-16 and back again:

```
(babel:octets-to-string (babel:string-to-octets (yason:parse "\"\\ud800\\udc00\"") :encoding :utf-16le) :encoding :utf-16le)
  => ""
```

You should be able to work around this by changing this line:

```
(yason:encode (funcall fn-convert (yason:parse data)) fout)
```

To use an intermediate string, which you convert to UTF-16 and back.

```
(write-sequence
 (babel:octets-to-string
  (babel:string-to-octets
   (with-output-to-string (outs)
    (yason:encode (funcall fn-convert (yason:parse data)) outs))
   :encoding :utf-16le)
  :encoding :utf-16le)
 fout)
```

I submitted a patch that has been accepted to fix this in yason:

https://github.com/hanshuebner/yason/commit/4a9bdaae652b7ceea79984e0349a992a5458a0dc